# Laravel auth middleware not keeping query string after redirect

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, middleware, laravel-middleware

We have a link which has some UTM code at the end like this:

https://website.com/guides/playing-live-touring/show-budget?utm_source=hubspot_weekly3_&utm_medium=email&utm_term=&utm_content=&utm_campaign=hubspot_weekly3_showbudget_19_11_12&utm_nooverride=1

This link is a gated page, so of course, the user is 302 redirected to https://website.com/login, but the query string is not kept.

I tried modifying the redirectTo method in the Authenticate middleware from

```
protected function redirectTo($request)
{
    if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
        return route('login');
    }
}
```

to

```
protected function redirectTo($request)
{
    if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
        return route('login', $request->query());
    }
}
```

but to no avail. Which is weird, because echoing `route('login', $request->query())` shows the correct URL.

Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: seems to work as expected for me ... what version of Laravel 5 are you using btw?

Comment: @lagbox Laravel 5.7